# CSS: Make "hover" of the "a" tag inside of "span" tag, gone

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a small problem with a `hover`. So I want to make `hover` of the `a` tag inside of `span` tag, gone.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<nav id="top-menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="file:///C:/Users/Misha/Desktop/amazon/amazon_site/home.html">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <span><a href="">Products</a></span> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Statistics</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Countries</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Settings</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Contacts</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is my CSS file:

```
nav#top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#top-menu ul li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #696969;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: #696969 solid 2px;
}

#top-menu ul li a:hover { border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px; }

#top-menu ul li span a{
    color: black;
}
```

So I add this to make `products``hover`, gone:

```
#top-menu ul li span a:hover { }
```

or

```
#top-menu ul li span:hover { }
```

But it didn't. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style the hover same as surrounding style (including text-decoration:none), and flag these as !important so they override the browser default stylesheet.

```
#top-menu ul li span a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-bottom: #696969 solid 2px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

The properties you have to specifically control, are the ones which the "hover" would normally style. Most typically, that might be color.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add hover for the a with `!important` like

```
#top-menu ul li span a:hover {
     border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px !important;
}
```

Because you have already given border-bottom to the anchor tag before.

Answer (score 0):

Say something like that for the span:

```
span a:hover{/*Nothing here*/}
```

It should negate the hover effect. Hope this helps.